# CLAPACK: error when testing CBLAS

Tags: lapack, blas

I am getting an error when i test CBLAS in CLAPACK. When i run the test code

```
./xblat2d < dblat2.in
```

I get the error output:

*"TransA must be 111, 112 or 113, but is set to -1Parameter 2 to routine cblas_dgemv was incorrect"*

Does anyone know what kind of problem this indicates?

### Details

I am trying not to use reference CBLAS, and use ATLAS CBLAS instead. So, i compiled wrapper library *libcblaswr.a* and changed the line in make.inc to

```
BLASLIB     = ../../libcblaswr.a -L/usr/local/atlas/lib -lcblas -L/usr/local/atlas/lib -latlas
```

CLAPACK installation suggest doing

```
BLASLIB     = ../../libcblaswr.a -lcblas -latlas
```

But linker doesn't find cblas and atlas without me using -L option, so i included it.

Details of my setup:

- Ubunty Lycid Lynx 10.04
- CLAPACK-3.2.1
- ATLAS.3.9.51

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a problem with the CLAPACK test in that it passes the wrong parameters to the BLAS routines. In calling dgemv there is an option for the matrix to operate as itself or as the transpose or as the conjugate transpose, corresponding to 111, 112 or 113 (see line 6 of cblas.h). The code in CLAPACK doesn't set the parameter correctly. I haven't looked deep enough to know if this is an issue with just the test or if the issue runs deeper; but I suspect it's just with the test as I haven't run in to this issue using any CLAPACK code.

I have ignored it because 1) I'm not depending on CLAPACK to test the BLAS routines installed by ATLAS and 2) if there's a deeper issue it will cause an error like this rather than produce invalid results, and I'll track it down then.

And yes, the linker won't find -lcblas and -latlas until you install them somewhere normally searched, this is normal.