# LAPACK and armadillo on ubuntu

Tags: lapack, armadillo

I've installed BLAS and LAPACK on my ubuntu and then Armadillo. In the `config.hpp` file the `ARMA_USE_LAPACK` is uncommented.
Programs compile without errors.
However, when I run them I get  `error: eig_sym(): use of LAPACK needs to be enabled`
The only solution I managed to find suggest to uncomment that flag in `config.hpp` file, but it happens to be already on.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: You may use `cmake`  : what is the output of `cmake .`  ?  Is there a file named CMakeList.txt in your folder ? Did it find lapack ( flag `LAPACK_FOUND`) and blas ? Then type `make` and `make install`

Comment: Thank you, I used `cmake .` and it finds BLAS and LAPACK, but not CBLAS and CLAPACK. However, it still gives me the runtime error.

Comment: Could be a problem related to the compiler http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862251/armadillo-c-matrix-library-how-to-enable-use-of-atlas-or-lapack . Looking at `include/armadillo_bits/auxlib_meat.hpp`, it seems that the only way to get `eig_sym(): use of LAPACK...` is to have `ARMA_USE_LAPACK` undefined.

Comment: Why not just install the Armadillo package that comes with Ubuntu?  It's all pre-configured to use BLAS and LAPACK, and you don't need to do any manual configuration.  Use Ubuntu's software/package installation tool to find the Armadillo package.  
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/armadillo/